# Why does my domain and ssl is not working correctly from every place?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a domain purchased at [1and1](https://www.ionos.com) and set up at AWS EC2 with SSL and Apache server.

Even the domain pointing to the correct IP (using nslookup I can see it), it works from some places and not from others.

For example, here from my workplace, I see this page (the domain does not reach the EC2 server):

[image]

I launched a Windows EC2 at AWS to make a test and from there, everything is correct (the page loads and SSL is valid):

[image]

From my client's computer, it has another behavior. It reaches the EC2 server, but is says the SSL is invalid:

[image]

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not enough is known about the setup of your domain and the differences between the environments where access shows different behavior. It looks like that you don't want to publish the URL so that one can try to get the necessary detail to debug the issue. In this case check  your domain with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) yourself and make sure that it does not report any problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. The first thing you need to do is get an Elastic IP, the instance IP can change during reboot etc but elastic IP are static IP’s so you should make sure you create one of them and assign it your running instance.
2. Create Hosted Zone and Record Sets
   Documentation is here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html
3. Create a recordset and add values
4. Add the Amazon NameSpaceServers in Control panel of Domain Provider
5. Import the SSl certificate to AWS Certificate manager (Optional). Documentation is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-api-cli.html#import-certificate-api
   Self signed certificate will not work.
6. Deploy the SSl certificate into Apache server and configure the traffic for https.
7. Open the AWS in-bond traffic port documentation is here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/